# icon_path isn't working in win10toast module in python

Tags: python-3.7

I'm attempting a countdown clock in python 3.7 using win10toast, time and playsound. Here's the code:

```
import time
import playsound
import win10toast

Toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier()

def countdown(y):
    while y > 0:
        print(y)
        y -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
    playsound.playsound('alarm-clock-ringing.mp3')
    Toaster.show_toast('Countdown notifier', 'countdown over', duration=9,
                       icon_path=r'D:\img.ico')


try:
    x = int(input('how many seconds do you want to countdown?: '))
    countdown(x)

except ValueError:
    print('That wasn\'t an integer! Please enter an integer!')
```

It works fine, except for icon_path in line 14. The error I'm getting is:

> ERROR:root:Some trouble with the icon (D:\img.ico): (0, 'LoadImage', 'No error message is available')

By the way, I'm using windows 10 pro 64-bit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First, convert the `.jpg` or `.png` file that u have into a `.ico` file. U can do it using python's `PIL` library like this:

```
from PIL import Image
filename = "logo.png"
img = Image.open(filename)
img.save('logo.ico')
```

Now, u have saved the logo as an `ico` file, so u can easily use it in ur code like this:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toast = ToastNotifier()

file_name = 'logo.ico'

toast.show_toast("Notification","Notification Body", duration=5, icon_path = file_name)
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: It worked; thanks! Any idea what was wrong with my file?

Answer (score 2):

**Hello!**

```
import time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Hello World!!!","Python is 10 seconds awsm!",icon_path= 
filename.ico,duration=10,threaded=False)
while toaster.notification_active():
          time.sleep(0.1)
```

**Copy and Paste,**
**Your Welcome :)**

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, LOAD-ICON should pick up the 32x32 version of the icon (if it exists)

- LOAD-IMAGE does not work if .ICO file contains a 256x256 icon.
- Using an ICO file with 32x32, 16x16, and/or 48x48 icons works.
- Icon files with several images work unless it contains a 256x256 version. In this case, no icon is loaded.

[for reference click here](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/LOAD-IMAGE-does-not-work-if-ICO-file-contains-256x256-icon)

Answer (score 1):

**just replace this:**

```
'D:\img.ico' ==> 'D:/img.ico'
```

**or use it in this way:**

```
'D:\\img.ico'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a .ico file, that would probably work..

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the answer.