# Notification icon does not show up - pynotifier module python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add an icon to my notification. I'm using `pynotifier` :https://pypi.org/project/py-notifier/

but the icon doesn't show up and throw this error:

```
ERROR:root:Some trouble with the icon (D:\notification\warning.ico): (0, 'LoadImage', 'No error message is available')
```

Code:

```
from pynotifier import Notification
import pathlib, os
current = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()

Notification(
    title="Hello",
    description="this is a notification",
    duration=5,  
    urgency=Notification.URGENCY_CRITICAL,
    icon_path=os.path.join(current, 'warning.ico')
).send()
```

There are some similar questions but none of them had a useful answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [icon\_path isn't working in win10toast module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621139/icon-path-isnt-working-in-win10toast-module-in-python)

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal same error

Comment: did you check if you can open `D:\notification\warning.ico` in any image viewer. OR maybe program works only with PNG, JPG files.

Comment: @furas the image opens correctly. also I tried other formats still getting error.